# Understanding neural network probability

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, cnn

I'm training a CNN model with two classes to predict. I know it gives me a probability for one class and for the other one, and I also know I can get the predicted label, but I don't the results given. Isn't the sum of the output for each evaluated input supposed to be equal 1.0? For instance:

```
[[0.2858745  0.85059494]
 [0.2858745  0.85059494]
 [0.6040499  0.5927084 ]
 [0.8403308  0.291448  ]
 [0.04195209 0.95504093]
 [0.79433376 0.21279709]
 [0.79433376 0.21279709]
 [0.01326967 0.9891382 ]
 [0.0153821  0.9867737 ]
 [0.79433376 0.21279709]
 [0.01617167 0.98520505]
 [0.01351487 0.98596036]
 [0.01473185 0.9846144 ]
 [0.00896762 0.9899838 ]
 [0.00936404 0.9893628 ]]
```

Is there something I didn't get?

Code:

```
model_05_01 = Sequential()
model_05_01.add(Conv1D(filters=16, kernel_size=12, 
                 input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], 1)))
model_05_01.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4))

model_05_01.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=12))
model_05_01.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4))

model_05_01.add(Conv1D(filters=16, kernel_size=12))
model_05_01.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4))

model_05_01.add(Flatten())

model_05_01.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model_05_01.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))

model_05_01.compile(loss='logcosh', optimizer='adam', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: What framework are you using?  What's the architecture of your network (esp. the last layer)?

Comment: Tensorflow. 3 Conv1D layers, + 2 Dense layers, the last one is `model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))`

Comment: Edit the post with the code.

Answer (score 1):

What you have declared here is actually a 2-class multi-label classifier. It is trying to learn the probability of being each class independently where they are *not mutually exclusive*.

While that is a valid classifier problem to solve, I'm guessing what you mean is that you have an exclusive 2-class problem: it's either positive, or negative. In that case, you want the final layer to be `Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')`